Reading words/names written in suetterlin
In 1936 my grandfather's cousin wrote my grandmother, the widow of his cousin, about her husband's family from Kastl near Amberg, Germany.
I have used Transkribus from readcoop.eu along with google to mostly figure out the first page of a family history entitled "Die Widenbauer"
Transkribus split screen showing suetterlin in left pane and transcription in right
He says that my 3rd great grandfather bought a brewery/tavern in 1802 of which I have a picture. Using google street view, I've found the original building on the Market plaza in Kastl. It's #2 Marktplazt and is on the historic walking tour: Marktplatz 2 | Gasthaus „Bäckastachl“
I can't make out the name of the tavern he bought (5th line from top).
It also says that he paid 12000 fl and 330 fl (Leikurh???????)
And that "Er ?? heiratete die einzige Tochter des Nachbars Schügl????"


OMG! I Comment only to praise anyone who could begin to understand any of that scribble…

I figured out the name of the tavern, it's "Zum Schwarzen Bär" (To The Black Bear)
There is currently an inn/hotel located at Marktplatz 13 on the other side of the street across from the brewery/tavern. It's called "Gasthof Schwarzer Bär"
